# Doubt about the impedance of the Instruments

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, electronics, electrical-engineering

It is correct to say that the instruments that measure signal have a large impedance as opposed to the instruments that generate signal, whose impedance turns out to be small.
I know that this is true of many laboratory equipment but can we generalize it as I explained before?

I really appreciate your time.

Comment: Ammeters need to have very low impedance as they need to be in series.

Answer (score 1):

This is generally true. the higher the sensor impedance, the less it perturbs the circuit being measured. The lower the signal source impedance, the better able it is to drive a variety of circuits. Ideal sensor impedance is 10 million ohms; typical source impedance is from 50 to 600 ohms.

Answer (score 0):

Laboratory instruments have the impedance which is best for the job.  For measuring voltages, this is typically high.  For generating signals, this is typically low.  For other tasks, other impedance are ideal.  For example, in many RF signalling situations, you want an impedance that matches that of the circuit under test.